# Specify terraform workspace in HCL

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to specify a workspace for a remote state provider in HCL? How do I ensure collaborators use the proper workspace? I'd expect to see something like

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    workspace = "someworkspace"
    ...
  }
}
```

Terraform's documentation describes how to use [workspace_key_prefix](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html#workspace_key_prefix) but that's not what I'm looking for.

For example, if one team member runs `terraform workspace select dev` then `terraform apply` then a different team member runs `terraform apply` **without** first running `terraform workspace` terraform will redeploy the resources defined (because the proper workspace wasn't selected).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here. If you select a workspace (using `terraform workspace select` or `terraform workspace new`) then Terraform will automatically separate the state file to be used. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do and what's not working for you?

Comment: Is this upcoming feature what you are looking for: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-remote-operations?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR PTAL added an example. The issue comes in when one team member uses `terraform workspace select dev` then `terraform plan`. When the next teammate run `plan` without first running `workspace` you'll get duplicate deployments.

Comment: Duplicate environments (or close enough modulo changes made using `terraform.workspace`) is what workspaces is meant to achieve. If you don't want that then you shouldn't use them.

Comment: 'Duplicate environments" is the wrong word. I'm more interested in specifying (via HCL) which environment any given plan should target. Following the best practices outlined in https://www.terraform.io/docs/enterprise/guides/recommended-practices/part1.html#one-workspace-per-environment-per-terraform-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround. You can commit the `environment` file to VCS (`.terraform/environment`). Others running `terraform apply` will target the workspace specified by the environment file.